# How to update value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following select statement.
I would like to update the values of ContactAssociate from 'Bob' to 'Jane'. Is it possible to do this?

```
SELECT TOP (1500) ContactID, ContactNotes, 
  ContactAssociate, ContactAppointment
FROM  
  tb_Contact
WHERE 
 (ContactAssociate = 'Bob') AND 
 (ContactAppointment = 0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE TB_CONTACT
   SET contactassociate = 'Jane'
 WHERE contactassociate = 'Bob'
```

The query you supplied checked for `contactappointment` being zero - if you wanted to include that check, the query would be:

```
UPDATE TB_CONTACT
   SET contactassociate = 'Jane'
 WHERE contactassociate = 'Bob'
   AND contactappointment = 0
```

The `UPDATE` statement doesn't support the `TOP` keyword, so your update statement would be:

```
UPDATE TB_CONTACT
   SET contactassociate = 'Jane'
 WHERE contactid IN (SELECT TOP (1500)
                            contactid 
                       FROM TB_CONTACT
                      WHERE contactassociate = 'Bob'
                        AND contactappointment = 0)
```

...but that will give random contacts - you should specify an `ORDER BY` clause in the subquery to get consistent results.

Reference:

- [UPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, as I said -  that will update all the records in the table though. I only want to update 1500 where the ContactAppointment column = 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tb_Contact SET ContactAssociate='Jane'
 WHERE ContactID IN
      (
           SELECT TOP (1500) ContactID
           FROM  tb_Contact
           WHERE (ContactAssociate = 'Bob') AND (ContactAppointment = 0)
      )
```

- For general tutorial on UPDATE see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_update.asp).
- For a specific reference for MSSQL see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662%28SQL.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that will update all the records in the table though. I only want to update 1500 where the ContactAppointment column = 0.

Comment: @Am: Better to link to vendor documentation - vendor agnostic is liable to miss details.

Comment: @Am: It's redundant to check for the associate name if it's already done in the subquery that will return primary keys.

Comment: Agreed, though if the OP is new, a "light" tutorial might be friendlier.

Comment: @Ponies: tnx, Fixed. I wonder if the query compiler would have fixed it anyways.

Comment: Missing the `WHERE` :)  Maybe, but I'd take any chance to use a primary key whenever I can.